# how to pass font family and fontsize dynamically to UILabel?

Tags: iphone, font-family

```
cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:8.0];
```

Is it possible to pass the name of the font family and size dynamically to  label text of the cell in iPhone?

```
NSString *selectorString =@"Helvetica-Bold";
cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:@"%@",selectorString];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can set like this

```
float fontSize = 14.0f;
NSString *selectorString =@"Helvetica-Bold";
cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",selectorString] size:fontSize];
```

Comment: Thanks for quick response ...any idea to passing font size dynamically  to label?

Answer (score 2):

Try this its helps you.

```
UILabel *titlelbl=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(80, 0, 150, 40)];
titlelbl.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:17];
titlelbl.textAlignment=UITextAlignmentCenter;
titlelbl.textColor=[UIColor blackColor];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#define FONT_HELVETICA_BOLD @"Helvetica-Bold"
#define FONT_SIZE 14.of

cell. textLabel.font=[UIFont fontWithName:FONT_HELVETICA_BOLD size:FONT_SIZE];
```